# php + jquery slider

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

here's the deal:
I've in a mysql db a table called `bank`. In there users have a balance.
Let's say I've 1500. How can I make a slider which goes from 0 to 1500? The point is to "withdraw" some of it...
I mean, I need to know what was the value that the user choosed so I can alter the table afterwards.

Briefing: I have a php variable (current balance), I need to have a slider with the proper range and then alter the table. Ex: 1500 - 500 = 1000 (I had 1500, withdrawn 500 and now I've 1000.

Comment: do you have the html? js? php? what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I don't know how to start.. I've a php page but I haven't started the slider thing because I don't know how

Comment: your tag to jquery ui-slider is a good start, full demo: https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: You can have a slider go between any two numbers you want. They're completely arbitrary, really.

Comment: Ok, let's say I have $value = 500;
How can I make a slider that goes from 0 to 500 and when I click submit I want to know what was the value chosen.

Comment: still what you got so far? where are you stuck? you have to make a start no one is writing it all for you.